# Navigation stack costmaps and explore_lite not working

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap

I am currently trying to use explore_lite with the navigation stack, but I am running into some issues. First of all, the navigation stack seems to be identifying the robot itself as an obstacle in the costmap as seen below, as the area where the robot started at is colored in black as an obstacle. This leads to the planner being unable to find paths to a goal, as the robot's previous positions in the map are added as additional obstacles.

The second issue I am running into is that the explore_lite package I am trying to use is not working. It is able to identify frontiers (marked by the green spheres below) and a goal (the red arrow), but the robot doesn't actually move towards it. This was working (but not well) before, but now it isn't, and I can't figure out why.

[image]

These are my configuration files and rqt graph-

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.4
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_vel_theta: 0.4
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.3

  acc_lim_theta: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: false
  
  sim_time: 1.0
  sim_granularity: 0.03
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.03
```

local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:

  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.025
  
  # ?
  origin_x: 0.0
  origin_y: 0.0
  
  map_type: costmap
  
  observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
  laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: camera_depth_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

costmap_common_params.yaml

```
obstacle_range: 5
raytrace_range: 3.0

# found using https://answers.ros.org/question/385798/how-can-i-find-the-appropriate-robot-footprint + jackal dimensions
footprint: [[-0.215, -0.254], [0.215, -0.254], [0.215, 0.254], [-0.215, 0.254]]

inflation_radius: 0.5
transform_tolerance: 1

controller_patience: 2.0

NavfnROS:
   allow_unknown: true

recovery_behaviors: [
   {name: conservative_clear, type: clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery},
   {name: aggressive_clear, type: clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery}
]

conservative_clear: 
   reset_distance: 3.00
   
aggressive_clear:
   reset_distance: 1.84

observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: camera_depth_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

rqt graph

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on this? I've been trying to figure these out for a while, but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I believe that explore_lite isn't working because of the robot's positions being marked as obstacles (the first question I had). This made it so that explore_lite thought the robot was inside of an obstacle to begin with and thus couldn't find any paths. I still don't know the answer to why the robot is marking itself as an obstacle, but I will close this question and make a new question to ask again.